# How to calculate FPS of a live video stream using Chrono and OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv, c++-chrono

For a while I've been trying to calculate the FPS of a video stream coming through my *OpenCV* program, and was wondering if there's any way to do it using *Chrono* rather than *time.h* or any other API that measures with CPU ticks. After a good amount of experimenting and researching, I haven't found a simple solution using *Chrono*.

Is there a Keep-It-Simple-Stupid solution to calculating your FPS with *Chrono*? Or is working with CPU ticks unavoidable?

Answer (score 1):

You got the method

[VideoCapture::get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS)](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html#aeb1644641842e6b104f244f049648f94) 
Is it not working?

As far as I know a chrono approach would still use CPU Ticks.
Supposing your loop is something like

```
cv::Mat frame; cv::VideoCapture cap(video_path);
while (cap.read(frame)) {
     /* .. */
}
```

You could try something like

```
#include <chrono>
using namespace std::chrono;

time_point<steady_clock> begin_time = steady_clock::now(), new_time;
cv::Mat frame; 
cv::VideoCapture cap(video_path);
size_t frame_counter = 0;

while (cap.read(frame)) {
    /* do stuff.. */ 
    frame_counter++;
    new_time = steady_clock::now();

    if (new_time - begin_time >= seconds{1}) {
        /* Do something with the fps in frame_counter */
        frame_counter = 0;
        begin_time = new_time;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Try your best to never use `.count()`:  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P32hvk8b13M&t=41m15s  Instead:  `new_time - begin_time >= 1s`, or in C++11:  `new_time - begin_time >= seconds{1}`

Comment: @HowardHinnant Fixed. Thanks :).